# How can I set the padding depending on the screen resolution

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

How can I set the padding depending on the screen resolution in Xamarin.Forms Android?

```
 _map.MyLocationEnabled = true;
        _map.UiSettings.MyLocationButtonEnabled = false;
        _map.TrafficEnabled = true;
        _map.SetMinZoomPreference(5f);
        _map.SetMaxZoomPreference(22f);
        _map.UiSettings.ZoomControlsEnabled = false;
        _map.MapType = GoogleMap.MapTypeNormal;
        _map.BuildingsEnabled = true;
        _map.UiSettings.CompassEnabled = true;
        _map.SetPadding(0,240,0,0);// ????????
```

Comment: is the question really how to get resolution on Android? Because if you know the resolution you can set padding.

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: And you mean screen size or screen density?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I set the padding depending on the screen resolution in Xamarin.Forms Android?

You can use the following codes to retrieve the resolution of your current device:

```
Display display=WindowManager.DefaultDisplay;
Point size = new Point();
display.GetSize(size);
int width = size.X;
int height = size.Y;
```

Then you can set the padding based on the resolution of your device.